# Small white flower used to decorate a cake, any idea what it might be called?

Tags: identification, flowers

I'm trying to find what the name of this flower is called.

It's used to decorate a cake, shown in the show Anne with an E inspired from Anne of Green Gables.

It doesn't appear to have any colouring in the middle, and I can't seem to find anything when I search for flowers from Prince Edward Island or Canada.

I've found quite a few similar flowers but they tend to have something in the middle of the flower. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably supposed to be a Canada Lily, though it's not a very good imitation IMO. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilium_canadense

Comment: Do you know whether the flowers and leaves are real, or fake, made from edible products? If they are real, what time of year was the cake made, and what part of the world are we talking about?

Comment: They are supposed to be real since it’s a period show. The scene involves a character gathering things outside such as Canadian holly, pine cones and such, located on Prince Edward Island in Canada, but I can’t quite say what season it’s from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The side flowers appear to be Galanthus Nivalis, but the flowers on top seem to be different. I'll see if I can find anything on them but with only the flower head it will always be a guess. The Galanthus around the cake have quite a few distinguishing features though.

EDIT: The white flowers on top appear to be Hyacinth flowers. Both bloom in early spring and grow in Canada.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering that! That definitely appears to be the closest in appearance on all accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The flowers on top are hyacinths, and the ones on the edges are called snow drops. They grow in the woods in early spring here in Canada, and in Europe as well!

Comment: This answer has already been given.  Although using Galanthus instead of the common name Snowdrop.